# Google App Engine PHP warmup script not running on live

Tags: php, google-app-engine, warm-up

I've written an app which uses Twitter's Firehose to stream tweets to a browser (using websockets). I had it working fine locally using Google App Engine Launcher, but now that it's deployed I've found that the warmup script - which subscribes to the Firehose stream - doesn't seem to run on startup.

`app.yaml`:

```
application: myappname-1331
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: warmup.php
  login: admin

- url: /
  script: main.php
```

I've reduced my `warmup.php` right down to:

```
<?php
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'Warmup running');
```

I'm not getting any entries in the GAE log viewer for warmup.php, although I am for all other scripts (ie ones hit via the browser).

Answer (score 0):

Warmup requests are only sent if you specific a minimum number of 'idle instances'.

It isn't really suitable for what you're doing - consider instead an instance set up for 'manual scaling' that responds to `/_ah/start`